# KENDO ui menU IE9 issue

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using KEndo UI in asp.net mvc website and menu is working fine in all the browsers except IE 9.0 . I am using float: right but when i open the page on IE 9 and move my mouse over the menu then it moves from right to left

[image]

But it should be like this

[image]

Mt CSS

```
 .float-right-menu {

    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Would need to see your HTML/CSS for the entire menu to help. Or better yet create a simple demo recreating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need some kind of css reset for those kind issues

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to IE :(  If I remember correctly, IE9 has an odd rendering bug where if your floated element doesn't have a width specified in CSS, then it decides to make it 100% width (like a non-floated div would be).
I think to fix it you have to give it a width in CSS. Unfortunately, that is hard to do unless you know the actual width of the menu. But, try setting it to something like "width: 300px;" just to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I have created a new sample project and how can i upload project here

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetMenuWidth()
    {
        var menu = $('#MenuName');
        menu.width(menu.width());
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetMenuWidth();
    });
</script>
```